# Run operation based on group in column 1 in csv

Tags: bash, shell, csv

I have a CSV having jarnames in column 2 which are grouped in Bundles A1 A2 .. in column 1. I want to run operations (copying (deploy) and some other operations) on one Bundle (say A1) at a time that means on collection of services from that Bundle. Also want to store the name of those services to check if the operation is complete for them if yes then work on second group.I check logs to see the name of those services with successful message.

I have achieved it through creating folder per group so that each folder has all jars and performing copy one folder at a time by reading csv (added new column ).I can continue using it but stuck how can hold name of services for a group.
to check logs.

```
OLDIFS=$IF
while IFS=, read -r bundle jarName 
do  
  echo --"$jarName"--
  echo --"$bundle"-- 
  if [[$bundle != "" ]]; then
    if [[ -d "$targetDir/$bundle/" ]]; then
      find $sourceDir/ -type f -name "$jarName*" -print0 | xargs -r 0    -i mv "{}" $targetDir/$bundle$/;
    else
      mkdir  $targetDir/$bundle
      find $sourceDir/ -type f -name "$jarName*" -print0 | xargs -r 0    -i mv "{}" $targetDir/$bundle$/;
    fi
  fi
```

done

---

```
OUTPUT- 
ls $targetDir
A1 
A2
A3..
```

Now want to deploy  this folders one by one and look for services name with in group  as with success in logs  then only  process for next group.
CSV****************************Below

```
A1,test1.jar,el
A1,test21.jar,el
A2,test3.jar,el
A2,test5.jar,el
A3,test7.jar
A4,test90.jar
```

I want to add something like 
    for i in $bundle{
    cp  $targetDir/$bundle/* 
    get jar names in this bundle and look  in logs for test1.jar success 
    test21.jar success then only proceed for A2.
    }

Comment: Can you please supply a snippet from the CSV? If it only has two columns, you can do something like `while IFS=, read -r ... done < myfile.csv`.

Comment: Snippet of csv would be helpful.

Comment: I have updated the question with CSV please see. The main thing I stuck with his how to hold the name of jars to track in log file if they are copied successfully. Log file is having shows those name after successful deployment.

Comment: Your csv file has more than two columns. You will need a dummy variable to receive the data from the rest of the line. Try: `while IFS=, read -r bundle jarName dummy` (it's also common to use an underscore as a dummy variable).